# Transfer all data to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, transfer

I want the code to transfer the rest of the data to sheet 5 after the number of data is less than 20 and we exit the loop.

````
Dim mycell As Range
Dim myrange As Range
Dim lastrow As Long
Set myrange = Worksheets("sheet3").Range("a2:a1000")
myrange.Interior.Pattern = xlnon
For Each mycell In myrange
For i = 1 To 20
If mycell.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Small(myrange, i) Then
mycell.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
mycell.Resize(1, 16).Cut Destination:= _
            Worksheets("sheet5").Range("a1").Offset(Worksheets("sheet5").Rows.Count - 1, 0).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

End If

Next
Next mycell
end sub ``` 



I want the rest of the data to be transferred to sheet 5 when exiting the loop below
````

Comment: From the code `If mycell.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Small(myrange, i)` it seems that you want to transfer the looped cell.resize(1,16) value if the looped cell value is in within the first to the 20th smallest value in `myrange`. Please CMIIW.